# Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException | Call to undefined relationship [neighborhood] on model [App\Models\Property]

Tags: php, laravel, model

hasOne(Address::class);
    }

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
    }

    public function goal()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Goal::class);
    }

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Type::class);
    }

    public function neighborhoods()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Neighborhood::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function pictures()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Picture::class);
    }
}

Comment: You should add more descriptions about your question to let others help you

Answer (score 0):

**For a Many To Many relationship you have to make sure that you have already created the pivot table**
in your case your pivot name table would be: property_neighborhood.
then you have to edit the neighborhoods() relationship as following:

```
public function neighborhoods()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Neighborhood::class , 'property_neighborhood', 'neighborhood_id', 'property_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to our community you have mistaken with the name of the relation
change **neighborhoods** to **neighborhood** without s

```php
public function neighborhood()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Neighborhood::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```